# Add range of mulitlevel index in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to add a column containing the range of the first level of a multi-level index in Python.
For example:

```
| Index1| Index2| count_of_Index1_Instances |  
---------------------------------------------
|   1   |  20   |           1              |
|       |  40   |           2              |
|       |  10   |           3              |
|   2   |  20   |           1              |
```

I know the`df.groupby(level=['Index1']).size()` command, but this is not what I am looking for. The result in the last column should be a range from 1 to the size of Index-Group1.
Some piece of code would be great!
Thank you!

Comment: Is this what you mean.. `df.groupby(level=['Index1']).cumcount().add(1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and add 1:

```
df['count_of_Index1_Instances'] = df.groupby(level=['Index1']).cumcount().add(1)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!